# Is BIP324 v2transport redundant on Tor and I2P connections?

Tags: bitcoin-core, encryption, tor, bip324-p2p-encryption, i2p

Just testing the recent **BIP324** on my node, since Bitcoin Core v26 and having `v2transport=1` in `bitcoin.conf` set, I have noticed that I am receiving some incoming connections using the v2 transport protocol to my node, which can only be reachable to incoming connection, using Tor and I2P, with my onion/I2P addresses, and if I make outgoing peer connections using the v2 transport protocol from my node to some Tor or I2P addresses, the connection is successful. It works without problems, ok.

But, **considering that these two networks are encrypted by design**, is it redundant to use this additional security layer for these networks? If, yes, shouldn't it **only be used for ipv4/ipv6** connections to avoid this unnecessary redundancy?

Refs:

https://support.torproject.org/about/

https://geti2p.net/en/

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0324.mediawiki

Comment: Have you read the link you included in reference? https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0324.mediawiki#motivation has a " Why not use a secure tunnel protocol?" section addressing BIP324 vs proxy networks (Tor, i2p, ..).

Answer (score 8):

The encryption aspect of BIP324 isn't very useful on Tor/I2P, but it's pretty cheap in terms of computation power (cheaper than the old unencrypted protocol on many systems!).

We could define a slimmed-down transport protocol to be used on these privacy networks (e.g. the BIP324 packet encoding, but without encryption or authentication tags), but I think the cost of yet another protocol isn't worth the benefits.